# Set criteria on column in which data is saved as a string JSON

Tags: java, sql, json, hibernate

I have following entities:

```
 public class **Product** implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Id_Gen")
        private Long id;


        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval =   true)
        @Fetch(value=FetchMode.JOIN)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_DETAILS_TABLE")
        private ProductJsonDetails productJsonDetails;

    }

@Table(name = "PRODUCT_DETAILS_TABLE")
    public class **ProductJsonDetails** implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Id_Gen")
        private Long id;

        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productJsonDetails")
        private Product product;

        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(name = "**XYZ_JSON**")
        private String **detailsJson**;

    }
    }
```

column **XyZ_JSON** has string in below format

*{"name" : "ABC","type":{"id" : "LMN", type : "CCC"}}*

**I want to set criteria as below:**

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Product.class, "product");

```
criteria.createAlias("product.productJsonDetails", "productJsonDetails", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

**critera.add (Restrictions.eq("productJsonDetails.type.id","1"))** - >>> This throws error.

How to set restriction on Id element of String json  ???

Comment: What error is the criteria throwing?

Comment: what is type here ?  cant you do it directly critera.add (Restrictions.eq("productJsonDetails.id","1"))